# Azure web app for containers - multiple docker run commands

Tags: docker, odoo, azure-container-service, azure-webapps

I am trying to deploy [this image](https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo) to azure web apps for containers.
Is it possible to run multiple docker run commands on app start?

the following are the commands I have to run:

```
$ docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=odoo -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres --name db postgres:10
$ docker run -p 8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t odoo
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to use docker compose

Answer (score 0):

After the container is created use as below example
docker exec -it [container_name] psql -U [postgres_user]